# push and reserve functions using stacks

Tags: stack, push

Looking for any help with why when I compile and run my program I get "Assign5.exe is not working" and then the program stops.

The push method takes an integer argument, the value to insert into the stack.
Determines if there is room in the stacks capacity, if there is not any room it calls a separate reserve method to increase the capacity by one or by twice as much.

The reserve method increase the stacks capacity and then copies all values in the stack array and stores them to print later.

The initial value being pushed in is this for loop:
    for (int i = 10; i < 80; i+= 10)
    s1.push(i)

This is my code thus far:

```
void Stack::push(int stackvalue)
  {
if (stkSize == stkCapacity)
  {
if (stkCapacity == 0)
reserve(1);
else
     reserve(stkCapacity * 2);
  } 

stkArray[stkSize] = stackvalue;
++stkSize;
  }




void Stack::reserve(size_t n)
  {
  if (n < stkSize or n == stkCapacity)
return;
  else
     {
  stkCapacity = n;
  int* tempArray;
if(stkCapacity == 0)
    tempArray = NULL;
else
  for (size_t i = 0; i < stkCapacity; i++)
     {
  tempArray[i] = stkArray[i];
     }

  delete[] stkArray;
  stkArray = tempArray;
  } 
     }
```